# using global vars in big backbone apps

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a rather general question, no code included.
What would be the best architecture using backbone/requirejs for big Backbone Apps?
Is it ok to have one global namespaces like App in which one can share all the necesary collections, models and views that are to communicate between each other? Or should I use just dependancy injection to load needed modules?

Comment: Why is there even a desire to revert/resort to globals? :<

Comment: Because some Views share Models/Collections and sometimes one needs some public methods from views to be used in controller and so on.

Comment: If you have methods which are to be used in common between different views (or similarly for controllers) you should consider creating a base View with those methods and extending it to create the different Views. Do add an example of the methods you have for more specific answers.

Comment: lets say I want to create a destroy method for some views and call it from the appController.js file. How could I do that without public vars. To pass all necessary views as a dependency does not seem natural. There might also a case where I share a model between 2 views and if one view modifies the model the other must be listening to the changes on the same instance.

Comment: For your first example you can create a superClass for these views and override its remove function and put your logic there. And for the second example it's the class that creates these 2 views that should create a single `model` and pass it to both views

Comment: Use dependency injection. Using big globals namespaces can quickly turn into a bad habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid global vars if you want your code to be reusable and modular

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, you can use a global namespace like `App` but just for class definitions not instances and maybe for utilities functions.

If you put instances in your global namespace you can finish up with all your views instantiated but only one is displayed, so the other instances:

- are using memory
- have listeners listening to dom elements and that may cause you a lot of problem
- can save it state when you navigate back to it, so it may requires you more efforts to initialize that state
  ...